# Is there a more efficient way of making div backgrounds and borders with CSS?

Tags: html, css

In my application, I have a large number of div's that have the same background and borders but have different sizes.

Using one specific background image for every single one of them is very inefficient, especially for bandwidth and performance.

I will show you the background div and border and will tell you what I want to do instead.

[image: This is what my div looks like]

So I thought it would be more efficient to separate the div into 4 corners (always the same ones), 4 sides (with background-repeat: repeat x or repeat y) and one center div

[image]

Do you think there is a better way of doing this with CSS 2? (I don't want to use CSS 3, for maximum compatibility)

Is this going to be resource-consuming for the client's browser or the server?

Comment: Box shadow and border radius support is very good. Use [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/) for polyfills to support old browsers. In my opinion using images for effects that CSS makes so trivial is in no way worth the effort. All your users will benefit—faster load times, etc—if you allow for graceful degradation.

Comment: Check this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146409/Semantic-HTML5-Page-Layout

Comment: I would use css3 in your case, because it's just round corner, the application doesn't break if the corner are not round on old browser

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I am looking into that. Regards

Comment: I completely agree with @bookcasey. Support for `border-radius` and `box-shadow` currently sits at 80% of users worldwide, and much higher if you're not targeting Asia (which is unlikely). Moreover, the natural degradation of these properties will leave your design practically intact with only a minor visual difference. Finding a solution that works across all browsers is likely going to result in worse performance for most of your users, plus make the markup/CSS harder to maintain in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Feel free to put it up as an answer. Thanks

Comment: If your border is something really fancy, SVG backgrounds might be an appropriate choice:  http://designfestival.com/a-farewell-to-css3-gradients/ and providing a graceful fallback for older browsers: http://www.broken-links.com/2010/06/14/using-svg-in-backgrounds-with-png-fallback/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would reccomend using `box-shadow` and `border-radius`:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 125px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  -o-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -1px 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wmGic)